# Erro ao instalar pacotes NPM sem sudo

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, osx

Estou com essa dificuldade, gostaria de saber se seria possível rodar sem `sudo`

```
MacBook-Air-de-Alan:~ collins$ npm i -g react-native-cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/collins/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/collins/.npm-global/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /Users/collins/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/collins/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/collins/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli'] {
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access ' +
npm ERR!     "'/Users/collins/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/collins/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/collins/.npm/_logs/2019-06-13T22_24_55_458Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Pode te ajudar: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o nvim para editar o arquivo ~/.bashrc e adicione essas linhas:

```
npm set prefix ~/.npm
PATH="$HOME/.npm/bin:$PATH"
PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

Após isso, rode o comando:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```